# Hot to use pytest capture logging.debug

Tags: python, pytest

This is a test example from [pytest document](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html), and I change `print` to `logging.warning`.

```py
import logging


def test_myoutput(capsys):  # or use "capfd" for fd-level
    print("hello")
    logging.warning("world")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "hello\n"
    assert captured.out == "world\n"
    print("next")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "next\n"
```

This test fails with:

```
========================================================================================== FAILURES ===========================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________ test_myoutput ________________________________________________________________________________________

capsys = <_pytest.capture.CaptureFixture object at 0x7fd80ac3b0d0>

    def test_myoutput(capsys):  # or use "capfd" for fd-level
        print("hello")
        logging.warning("world")
        captured = capsys.readouterr()
        assert captured.out == "hello\n"
>       assert captured.out == "world\n"
E       AssertionError: assert 'hello\n' == 'world\n'
E         - world
E         + hello

test.py:9: AssertionError
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING  root:test.py:6 world
```

So how can I capture `logging.warning` or `logging.debug` in pytest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented, no? Apparently, pytest does it itself. https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html